# The same C program does not work on Windows, but works perfectly on Linux

Tags: c

I have written a very basic program to read very large number from file and calculate the maximum product of consecutive numbers. To remind some C basics I decided to write it in C. On my home machine with Linux, it worked like a charm. On Visual Studio 2013 Express it throws some error and hangs (probably something with memory management). Do you have any clues what is going on?

```
int ch, i = 0, *ptr, count = 0, j;
FILE *f;
int *arr;

//Opening file in read mode
f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Error");
    return 0;
}

//intial allocation
arr = malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(int));
ptr = arr;

while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == 10) {
        continue; //exclude new line character
    }
    *ptr = (ch - 48); //populating array

    ptr++;
    count++;
    arr = realloc(arr, (count + 1) * sizeof(int));
}

int p0 = 1;
int maxp = 1;

//calculating largest product of five consecutive digits 
for (i = 0; i < count - 5; i++) {
    p0 = 1;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        p0 *= arr[i + j];
    }
    if (maxp < p0) {
        maxp = p0;
    }
}

printf("%d", maxp);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: What errors are generated? Where does it hang?

Comment: ...and what's the content of test.txt ?

Comment: "Do you have any clues what is going on?" No, but your Visual Studio does. And it told you. And you did not listen but clicked the message away. Go back and listen to the only one who knows the facts.

Comment: At least, error 1: No fclose. Error 2: No free.

Comment: Code not compilable, will not bother. (Missing `main()`, no includes.)

Comment: I'll never be tired of this: "the fact that it works doesn't mean it's correct". You have an error, that linux/gcc tolerate. The only other possible explanation (compiler bug) is really very rare. You have to start investigating for the 1st one - and you do have clues.

Comment: @nvoigt: I compiled with Visual Studio 2012 and I didn't get warnings apart from fopen being unsafe.

Comment: @MichaelWalz and the fact that you got errors? You got errors! That means *somebody* already figured out what is wrong and told you. And you ignored the message. You didn't even post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop you reallocate your buffer each time (which BTW is totally inefficient, but that's another story). But you continue to use the `ptr` pointer which points into the buffer that has been allocated by malloc just before the while loop. The realloc function **may** return the same address as the address of the previously allocated pointer, in which case your program seems to work. But if the returned address is **different**, `ptr` is no longer valid and your program won't work and it may even crash.

This should work (still as inefficient though) :

```
while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
    if (ch == 10) {
        continue; //exclude new line character
    }

    arr[count++] = (ch - 48); //populating array
    arr = realloc(arr, (count + 1) * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Thank YOU ! Could you tell how to make it efficient? :)

Comment: `realloc` can be relatively slow. You should allocate a buffer of say 1000 characters, fill the buffer and only when it is full you call realloc in order to increase the size by another 1000 characters.